# Tikz Tree Positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am trying to achieve the following with tikz:

[image: Example image]

I am having difficulty with figuring out how to tell tikz to start drawing trees at a node; as well as getting the direction of the tree correct. The MWE demonstrates my problems.

Any assistance would be appreciated. I am sure this is a very simple issue, however I have never been able to understand tikz.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{trees}
        \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
        \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (i) at (0,0);
\coordinate (o) at (2.5cm,0);
\coordinate (s) at (60:2.5cm);

\draw [] (0,0) -- (60:2.5cm) -- (2.5cm,0) -- cycle;

\node at (s) [above = 1mm of s] {S};
\node at (i) [below = 1mm of i] {I};
\node at (o) [below = 1mm of o] {O};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=up,
thestyle/.style={align=center}, 
sibling distance=4cm, 
level distance=1.5cm
]

\node at (s) [anchor=north]{}
    [edge from parent fork up]
child {node[thestyle] (s1) {S1}}
child {node[thestyle] (s2) {S2}}
child {node[thestyle] (s3) {S3}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right,
thestyle/.style={align=center}, 
sibling distance=4cm, 
level distance=1.5cm
]

\node at (i) [anchor=east]{}
    [edge from parent fork down]
child {node[thestyle] (i1) {I1}}
child {node[thestyle] (i2) {I2}}
child {node[thestyle] (i3) {I3}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=left,
thestyle/.style={align=center}, 
sibling distance=4cm, 
level distance=1.5cm
]

\node at (i) [anchor=west]{}
    [edge from parent fork down]
child {node[thestyle] (o1) {O1}}
child {node[thestyle] (o2) {O2}}
child {node[thestyle] (o3) {O3}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every `tikzpicture` is independent from the others unless you use a `remember picture` option.

As you want to draw a triangle and three trees inside the same picture, it's better that you use `scopes`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{trees}
        \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
        \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (i) at (0,0);
\coordinate (o) at (2.5cm,0);
\coordinate (s) at (60:2.5cm);

\draw [] (0,0) -- (60:2.5cm) -- (2.5cm,0) -- cycle;

\node (S) at (s) [above = 1mm of s] {S};
\node (I) at (i) [below left = 1mm of i] {I};
\node (O) at (o) [below right = 1mm of o] {O};

\begin{scope}[grow=up,
thestyle/.style={align=center}, 
sibling distance=2cm, 
level distance=1.5cm
]

\node at (S.north) [anchor=north]{}
    [edge from parent fork up]
child {node[thestyle] (s1) {S1}}
child {node[thestyle] (s2) {S2}}
child {node[thestyle] (s3) {S3}};
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[grow=left,
thestyle/.style={align=center}, 
sibling distance=2cm, 
level distance=1.5cm
]

\node at (I.west) [anchor=east]{}
    [edge from parent fork left]
child {node[thestyle] (i1) {I1}}
child {node[thestyle] (i2) {I2}}
child {node[thestyle] (i3) {I3}};
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[grow=right,
thestyle/.style={align=center}, 
sibling distance=2cm, 
level distance=1.5cm
]

\node at (O.east) [anchor=west]{}
    [edge from parent fork right]
child {node[thestyle] (o1) {O1}}
child {node[thestyle] (o2) {O2}}
child {node[thestyle] (o3) {O3}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi, and also thanks for pointing me to scopes and remember picture!

Answer (score 5):

This is really not an answer to your question, the one by [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi) is very good.

This is an alternative to draw your picture directly with tikz, with a `\foreach` command and also with a `scope` that changes the axes as needed.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \def\h  {2}    % triangle height (2/3)
  \def\tw {1.5}  % tree width
  \def\th {0.25} % tree hegiht (branches)
  \def\sep{0.25} % separations
  \coordinate  (S) at  (90:\h);
  \coordinate  (I) at (210:\h);
  \coordinate  (O) at (330:\h);
  \draw[thick] (S) -- (I) -- (O) -- cycle;
  \foreach\c/\x in {S/0,I/1,O/-1}
  {%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\c)},x={({1-abs(\x)},-\x*\x cm)},y={(-\x cm,{1-abs(\x)})}]
      \node at (0,\sep) {\c};
      \draw (-\tw,\th+3*\sep) -- (-\tw,3*\sep) -- (\tw,3*\sep) -- (\tw,\th+3*\sep);
      \draw (0,\th+3*\sep) -- (0,-\th+3*\sep);
      \foreach\i in {1,2,3}
      {%
        \node at ({\tw*(\i-2)},\th+4*\sep) {\c\i};
      }
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]